# Window resize doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu that on hover above 990px it opens the menu but when its below, the menu turns into a hamburger menu and you need to open it. The problem is I want to disable the hover when below 990px. This only works when the window is opened below 990px. If it starts above 990px and is reduced to below 990px, the window keeps the hover state on since the window opened above the 990px mark. I tried to add a resize() to it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
        $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
        });
    }else if ($(window).width <= 992) {
                $('.navbar .dropdown').off('mouseenter');
            }
});
```

Now when the window resizes, it disables the hover completely no matter what.

Comment: What is the point of this code `($(window).resize() < 990)`?  Are you missing an `if` and shouldn't you be using `.width()`?   `$(window).resize()` accepts an event listener function.

Comment: if i use a width its asking about when the windows opens not when its resized

Comment: I know this is potentially off topic but have you tried using CSS breakpoints and css3 animations to do this work?

Comment: `$(window).resize()` does not return a number.  So `($(window).resize() < 990)` makes no sense at all.  It's just wrong.  I don't know what you intended.

Comment: im trying to say when the window resizes below 990, to take off the hover event

Comment: You do realize that  `$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () { location.href = this.href; });` is just replicating the native browser functionality for anchors, right?

Comment: can you please give us and the html code so we can see what is happening because we can't understand what's happening if we don't see it

Comment: did any of the answers helped you ?

Comment: no its not, resizing doesn't work still, I updated the code above to relay my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with and it works for future reference:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function (e) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

        });

        $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () {
            location.href = this.href;
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var win = $(window).width();
        if (win >= 992) {
            $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
            });
            // this takes off the hover event if using on desktop
        } else if (win < 992) {
            $('.navbar .dropdown').off('mouseenter');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong because `$(window).resize();` is a event that is triggered when the window size is changed and it doesn't return a number.  Here is a good explanation [post](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_resize.asp) of the `.resize()`

```
($(window).resize() < 990)
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () {
        location.href = this.href;
    });
}
```

change to this

```
else if($(window).width() <990){
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () {
        location.href = this.href;
    });
}
```

or just simply

```
else{
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () {
        location.href = this.href;
    });
}
```

Comment: This also assumes you have a resize function elsewhere that calls this function with the answers modification.

Comment: Yes he should have a resize event and inside the resize function he should call all this code he has posted here with the fixes that i wrote in my answe :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a trigger for your code on resize event

```
$(window).resize(function() { /* do what you want */})
```